# how to change value of a column with respect of 3 groups

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data

```
     SAMPN MODE1 HHVEH PERNO PLANO loop
30    23     2     3     1    25    2
31    23     1     3     2     2    2
32    23     2     3     2     5    2
33    24     1     1     1     2    2
34    24     1     1     1     3    2
35    24     1     1     1     4    3
36    24     1     1     1     5    3
37    24     2     1     2     2    2
38    24     3     1     2     4    2
39    25     2     2     1     2    2
40    25     2     2     1     4    2
41    25     2     2     2     2    2
42    25     2     2     2     3    2
43    27     4     1     1     2    2
44    29     1     0     1     2    2
45    29     1     0     1     3    2
```

I want to do 2 things:

1- SAMPN is household and PERNO index of each person in each household. PLANO is trips of each person and loop is tour of each person. (each tour is made with some trips). and MODE1 mode of each trip.

If MODE1==2, I want mode of same SAMPN,PERNO and loop to be 2 as well.

```
 dput(r[30:45,1:6])
structure(list(SAMPN = c("   23", "   23", "   23", "   24", 
"   24", "   24", "   24", "   24", "   24", "   25", "   25", 
"   25", "   25", "   27", "   29", "   29"), MODE1 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), HHVEH = structure(c(4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), PERNO = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), PLANO = structure(c(20L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c(" 2", 
" 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "20", "23", "25", "29"), class = "factor"), 
    loop = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor")), row.names = 30:45, class = "data.frame")
```

output:

```
     SAMPN MODE1 HHVEH PERNO PLANO loop
30    23     2     3     1    25    2
31    23     2     3     2     2    2
32    23     2     3     2     5    2
33    24     1     1     1     2    2
34    24     1     1     1     3    2
35    24     1     1     1     4    3
36    24     1     1     1     5    3
37    24     2     1     2     2    2
38    24     2     1     2     4    2
39    25     2     2     1     2    2
40    25     2     2     1     4    2
41    25     2     2     2     2    2
42    25     2     2     2     3    2
43    27     4     1     1     2    2
44    29     1     0     1     2    2
45    29     1     0     1     3    2
```

when SAMP is 23 and PERNO=2 and loop=2 (second row ), 1 should be 2 because of third column. same for line 38.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `case_when`.  Grouped by 'SAMPN', 'PERNO', check if there are `any` 2s in 'MODE1', then return 2 or else return the 'MODE1'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(SAMPN, PERNO, loop) %>%
    mutate(MODE1 =  case_when(any(MODE1 == 2)~ 2L,
                              TRUE ~ as.integer(MODE1)))
# A tibble: 16 x 6
# Groups:   SAMPN, PERNO, loop [9]
#   SAMPN   MODE1 HHVEH PERNO PLANO loop 
#   <chr>   <int> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
# 1 "   23"     2 3     1     25    2    
# 2 "   23"     2 3     2     " 2"  2    
# 3 "   23"     2 3     2     " 5"  2    
# 4 "   24"     1 1     1     " 2"  2    
# 5 "   24"     1 1     1     " 3"  2    
# 6 "   24"     1 1     1     " 4"  3    
# 7 "   24"     1 1     1     " 5"  3    
# 8 "   24"     2 1     2     " 2"  2    
# 9 "   24"     2 1     2     " 4"  2    
#10 "   25"     2 2     1     " 2"  2    
#11 "   25"     2 2     1     " 4"  2    
#12 "   25"     2 2     2     " 2"  2    
#13 "   25"     2 2     2     " 3"  2    
#14 "   27"     4 1     1     " 2"  2    
#15 "   29"     1 0     1     " 2"  2    
#16 "   29"     1 0     1     " 3"  2
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[, .I[any(MODE1 ==2)],.(SAMPN, PERNO, loop)]$V1
df1[i1, MODE1 := 2L][]
```

Comment: I think you missed loop in group_by

Comment: @hghg Thank you.  I think the first 2 groups also worked with the example

Comment: do you have any idea about this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58064132/how-to-add-some-value-of-columns-with-respect-of-3-groups